# Python: signals-based high performance communication system

Tags: python

I am working on a python framework for building a special kind of editors (so they have GUI) and I just split it into backend and a frontend (distinct libraries), s.t. another frontend could be implemented in the future. I started the project with Qt (PySide2) and because there is potential for realtime data processing applications using this framework I want to enable threading compatibility (keeping the backend in a separate thread). Therefore the components from the separate ends only communicate via Qt's signals now, which is the default way to communicate between different threads in Qt. However, I would like to make to backend completely Qt-independent, so because the signaling system is quite useful I am looking for something to replace the signals that can be used in a similar way. Any suggestions?

Somebody actually suggested using something like ZeroMQ or "scalability protocols" since, apparently, the software "might soon have the need to scale to supercomputers" or in general more distributed computing systems for high performance computing. I never worked with such solutions, though, so I can't really tell what's the best way to go. Hence, I'd appreciate some tips :)

Comment: Are you looking for in-process (like between threads), between-process on the same computer (some kind of IPC), or something more general between computers?  Because when "somebody" says it "might soon have the need to scale to supercomputers" I'm not sure whether you're still in-process anymore.

Comment: I intentionally didn't specify this further. As I wrote, it's basically about inter-thread-communication but it wouldn't be bad to directly go for something that supports more (if there is something that does), as the software can be extended by the developer.

Comment: to the person downvoting the question: if you downvote, please explain *why*, thank you